# Pass down function with multiple parameters to child component w/ TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass a function as a prop to a child component in React but TypeScript is giving me errors. I have a function as such:

```
const submitData = (title: string, year: string): void => {
  // DO STUFF
};

// PASS IT TO CHILD
<ChildComponent
  submitData={submitData("do", "stuff")}
/>
```

And in my Child component I pass the type and add it like such:

```
interface ChildComponentProps {
  submitData: (a: string, b: string) => void,
};

const ChildComponent: React.FC<ChildComponentProps> = ({submitData}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={() => submitData("stuff", "do")}>
      //// etc. etc. etc.
    </div>
  )
};
```

I keep getting an error at the line where I pass it to the child component. It says:

`Type 'void' is not assignable to type '(a: string, b: string) => void'.`

Clearly the original submitData-function is not of `type "void"` but a function with two parameters. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're invoking `submitData()` in your parent component when you do `submitData={submitData("do", "stuff")}`. Since `submitData()` is invoked, its return value is passed down as props to `<ChildComponent>`, not the reference to the function.

Comment: submitData={submitData}

Comment: I feel like a fool, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You aren't passing the submitData function as a prop. You are passing the result of calling submitData. Simply change it to

```html
<ChildComponent
    submitData={submitData}
/>
```